# Laravel nested routes path

Tags: laravel

**This is is my routes.php**

```
 use App\Site;
 use App\Report;


 Route::get('sites/{site_id}/report/{report_id}', array('as'=>'Reports'), 
   function($site_id, $report_id){ 

   return view('reports')->with('site_id',$site_id)  
   ->with('report_id', $report_id);

  });
```

**And here is my view (reports.blade.php)**

```
  @foreach($reports as $report)
   <tr>
    <td>{{$report->url}}</td>
    <td>{{$report->recipient}}</td>
    <td>{{$report->email_date}}</td>
    <td><a href="{{route('Reports',['site_id'=>$report->site_id], 
    ['report_id'=>$report->report_id])}}">view</a>  |
   </tr>
  @endforeach   
</tbody>
```

**Error:**
*Missing required parameters for [Route: Reports] [URI: sites/{site_id}/report/{report_id}]. (View: /home/vagrant/apps/reporting-tool/resources/views/newsite.blade.php)*

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

**Additional Information** : I have two different tables which is site and report.

Comment: Replace `], [` with `,` in your `route('Reports')` function; the second parameter is an array, which is passed to your route definition, but you're passing 3 parameters.

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis

Comment: The supplied answer is demonstrating the same thing; be sure to upvote/accept it when you can.

Comment: @TimLewis its running already on my newsite.blade.php but when i click the url that you've fixed my localhost is not returning any of the following id it looks like this http://localhost:8000/sites//report

Comment: That just means that `$report-site_id` and `$report->report_id` are `null`. Confirm what `$report` contains and pass the correct values to your `route()` function.

Comment: I got it now thank you so much @TimLewis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second parameter of `route` helper should contain an array with both route variables:

```
route('Reports', ['site_id' => $report->site_id, 'report_id' => $report->report_id])
```

Comment: It work @SevaKalashnikov but my localhost when i clicked my view is like this
http://localhost:8000/sites//report it did not called the value of the site_id and report_id

Comment: Should `$report->report_id` just be `$report->id`?

Comment: Well, the original issue is fixed, now it seems like @Christian you have to troubleshoot and pass the right data to the `route` helper

Comment: @TimLewis no its report_id and site_id but they are from two different tables